# VS 2008 and Source control Explorer Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I faced a problem in Visual studio 2008.When i click on Sorce Control Explorer(Views-> Other Windows-> Source control Explorer)
The IDE was not responding.

So i googled and got a solution here(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952102).

The cause was " The problem is the vssprovider.dll failed to load."

**And the solution was**

Remove vssprovider.dll from the list of packages to skip by running:

**devenv.exe /resetskippkgs**

I implemented this solution and it worked.

**But i have few questions here**

1) what is this command actually doing ? Is that the right way to to remove vssprovider.dll .

2) Will this afffect the devolopment in future and throw some unexpected error/behavour in IDE ?

3) what is the role of vssprovider.dll ?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

SNA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You had Visual Source Safe source control provider set as default, while not having VSS installed. This command removed the non-existant provider from loading.
2. No, you just removed a non-exitsing entry
3. It's a connector to Visual Source Safe version control system.

Comment: HI but should i alwyas use devenv.exe /resetskippkgs command to open Visual studio.I canot use the Start-> Progrramme-> MVS2008 option.